# python import from a sub-sub directory

Tags: python, import

I have a folder structure as:

```
mainapp.py
+Level1
   __init__.py
   +Level2
       helper.py
       __init__.py
       utilities.py
       testapp.py
```

In mainapp.py I wish to import helper.py. I am able to do that using

```
import Level1.Level2.helper
```

helper.py is imported, but in trying to resolve helper.py's imports it fails. IN this case helper.py has

```
from Level2 import utilities
```

Which throws an

```
ImportError: No module named Level2
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it the way I'm trying to import? All the examples I found were only trying to go one level deep, and I tried following the same guidance to no avail.

I am using Python3

EDIT: LEVEL1 and below are external library I downloaded. I cant modify them. In level2 is a testapp that comes with the library that uses both helper and utilities. Running this test app works.

But I need to be able to use these files from my main app that lives 2 folders up

EDIT2: I believe my problem stems from my working directory being the directory that mainapp.py lives in. When I import using the fully qualified path LEvel1.Level2.helper that works, but once helper attempts to import Level2, there is no level2 in my current working directory. Is there a way to alias this? Or somehow have their imports relative to their location, not my working directory?

Comment: why not respecting the path?

Comment: I dont know what you mean?

Comment: just try `import utilities`

Comment: I cannot modify any of the files below Level1

Comment: Regarding EDIT2, that's what adding Level1 in your PYTHONPATH will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a python script it is important from where you are executing the script because that path becomes one of the relative paths from where the `import`s (all imports) are going to search for the packages/modules. I'm talking about the [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

So, knowing nothing else about the library, you could simply add the `Level1` path into the `sys.path` and sort of expose internal `Level2` sub-package to the world.

Assuming you are in a bash shell in the same folder as your `mainapp.py` you can add the `Level1` path to `sys.pah` using [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH):

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=./Level1
```

Then `helper.py` will be able to find the `utilities` module even executing your `mainapp.py` from *outside*.

Opinion:

I don't know the library and how it works, but in my opinion, importing from the same package using the package name itself it's not correct or at least not a good practice. And here you have an example, *you can only import that package if you are in the same level or in the parent one*. And probably the test app is working because, as you say, it is in the same package (level) that the `utilities`.

Original answer:

What you need is called [Intra-package References](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references). In your specific case as `utilities` and `helper` are in the same *level* you need:

```
from . import utilities
```

Comment: I just edited my original statement but I cant modify the helper or utilities code. They are a library that I downloaded.  Inside of level2 is another app.py which is their original app and it all works fine if you call from their app.

Comment: I updated the answer according to the new info provided.

Answer (score 1):

helper.py is inside the Level2 module, so that's implied in its import context.  The import line in helper.py should instead be

```
import utilities
```

Alternatively, you could add the path to Level1 to your PYTHONPATH.  This will allow you to directly import all modules under Level1 without additional namespace, e.g.

```
from Level2 import utilities
```

Which sounds like what you need, based on your edit.  There is probably a third option involving patching sys.modules, but that would involve patching sys.modules.

Comment: I just edited my original statement but I cant modify the helper or utilities code. They are a library that I downloaded.  Inside of level2 is another app.py which is their original app and it all works fine if you call from their app.

Comment: I added an alternative to my post